# Websphere - User fault processing is not supported

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

I have a problem with a webservice in Websphere ( although the same code is running quite fine in Wildfly ).
It is possible to generate a WSDL but I am not able to create a request in SOAPUI, because I always get the message:

User fault processing is not supported.The @WebFault faultbean is missing for ...

I do not have any annotation in my source code with @WebFault.

Is it possible to deactivate this "security" in Websphere without changing too much in the source code?
Since, it is running in Wildfly without any problems I think there must be an easy solution.

Maybe, somebody could help me please.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest you paste your SEI (web services interface) and your complete Exception class definitions.

Comment: Is it WebSphere or SOAPUI that is throwing this exception?

Comment: Sorry for my very late answer: I use RemoteException in Java, so it is very likely that it is being thrown from there. Regarding the Exception class: There is not any Exception class written by myself. The RemoteException is just thrown.